# How to fit image data column each image on one page

Tags: .net-core, stimulsoft

I'm using Stimul Report to create a report page. The report page shows correctly. I am reading an image for the stimulsoft web report from database.

Result shows many record image show two images on one page. But I want to show each image on a separate page.

[image]

This my code

```
 foreach (StiPage page in report.Pages)
 {
     page.Orientation = StiPageOrientation.Portrait;
     page.Margins.Top = 0;
     page.Margins.Bottom = 0;
     page.Margins.Left = 0;
     page.Margins.Right = 0;

     page.PaperSize = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A3;;  

     page.UnlimitedHeight = false;
     page.CanBreak = false;
}

var image = report.GetComponentByName("Image1") as StiImage;
image.CanBreak = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1 -

If you want to create one page for each record you can insert **Panel** in each page.

- Set Panel **Dock Style** property to **Fill**;
- And then place all your page components in it;
- Set Panel **Border** property to **All**. if you dont want border around your data, you can set borders color to **Transparent**. but borders is needed for prevention of decreasing panel size.

---

### 2 -

Instead of creating one page for each record you can create one page template and use this and pass your list to report.

For break page after each record(Person) you can use GroupHeaderBand and GroupFooterBand.

1. Place **GroupHeaderBand** before of record template;
2. Set headerband **Condition** property to your **Page Number field** like PageNumber;
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcnlT.png
3. Place **GroupFooterBand** at end of the record template;
4. Set  footerband **New Page After** property to **True**.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTq5E.png

These two bands will show for each record and page breaks after each GroupFooterBand.